# R - Storing for loop output for Reverse Geo coding (google api)

Tags: r

```r
y <- data.table()
for(i in 1:50){
  latlng <- list("latlng" = paste(myContent$lat[i],myContent$lon[i],sep = " " ),key = "XXXX")
  response <- GET(url, query = latlng)
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  if(response$status_code == 200){
    apiResponse <- fromJSON(content(response, "text"))
  }
  else{
    print("Error with Request")
  }
data <- rbind(y,apiResponse$results$formatted_address)
}
```

I need the loop to be able to get 50 addresses from lat and lon but only the last geocode combination is being used. I understand I need to store the output of each loop iteration, but I am confused how to do so. First time asking a question, please be merciful. Thank you!

Comment: Change data to y in the last line

Comment: `library(googleway)` which has a [reverse_geocode](http://symbolixau.github.io/googleway/reference/google_reverse_geocode.html) function which may help too.

Comment: Never call `rbind` in a `for` as it leads to excessive copying.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of data frames with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) since you are running elementwise loop between vectors. Then, `rbind` once together at the end. You can run the loop via a generalized function of your process:

```
get_address <- function(lat, lon) {
   latlng <- list(latlng = paste(lat, lon),
                  key = "XXXX")
   response <- GET(url, query = latlng)
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
   if(response$status_code == 200){
      apiResponse <- fromJSON(content(response, "text"))
   }
   else{
      print("Error with Request")
   }

   return(apiResponse$results$formatted_address)
}

df_list <- Map(get_address, myContent$lat, myContent$lon)

df_list <- Filter(NROW, df_list)    # REMOVE EMPTY DATA FRAMES
df_list <- Filter(length, df_list)  # REMOVE EMPTY NULL ITEMS

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```